# Two conditions failure in teradata case - NOT NULL AND NOT 0

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata

Trying to return a column, giving 1, when `column1` is `NOT NULL` and different than 0. So far managed to do this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN CASE WHEN column1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE 0 END)
```

Getting this error:

> SELECT Failed. 2620: The format or data contains a bad character.

It works quite ok with `NOT NULL` as a single condition, though.

Comment: it looks like in the nested CASE you have to add '=' after column1, something like this: `CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @HRK - yeah, true. Thanks. :) But now I have another error. Hopefully will manage to edit quickly :)

Comment: I don' t see any need to nest anything here.  `when column1 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end` covers everything. For your 2620 error, what data type is column1 ?

Comment: @Andrew - idk, it is a VIEW and somehow I do not have access. I imagine the worst possible floating comma or something similar, including a possible hidden comma/dot decimal separator issue.

Comment: Well, at a guess since it's failing this way, it's a char/varchar column. Try using single quotes around your 0s and 1s.

Comment: Yes, `CASE WHEN column1 <> '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` returns 0 for NULL as well as for nonzero values. Or if the intent is to do numeric comparison use `TRYCAST` to convert column1 to a number or return NULL if it's not a valid number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to nest anything, but it looks like you're missing the non-equality sign.

You might try,

```
CASE
  WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL AND column1 <> 0
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Alternatively, this will produce the same result as an OR operator, where, but CASE executes the WHEN clauses in order.

```
CASE
  WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL
  THEN 1
  WHEN column1 <> 0
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

But in your description, it sounds like you wanted BOTH conditions to be true, so it doesn't make sense to nest or use multiple WHEN statements, because you can just connect them together with `AND`

Comment: True, HRK mentioned it in the comments. Does it work with a simple `AND` evaluating first the left, then the right one?

Comment: The ordering in AND doesn't matter because BOTH have to be true... but within the CASE portion itself, the WHEN's will be evaluated in order from first to last. I'll add an alternative to show you how you can control the order